# dynamic routing for same pages name in asp webform

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 pages:
1 . localhost://temp1/default.aspx
and
2 . localhost://temp2/default.aspx
How 2 page'm calling like this:
if user go to for example test1.aspx
go to number 1 but this address
localhost://default
and if user go to the test2.aspx
go to number2 and same address (localhost://default)

so,How is ِDaynamic routing in asp webform?